# How `console.log` printing output instead of `console.log()`

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

How `console.log` is printing the output hence it's a console method and needs to be used with parenthesis. Now I feel there is something interesting about which I'm not aware.

For example:

```
new Promise((resolve)=> resolve(5))
.then(data=> console.log(data))
.then(Promise.resolve(10).then(console.log));

// Output: 5 10
```

Can someone explain how it's working and why?

Comment: `.then` takes a callable. `console.log` is callable. `.then(data=> console.log(data))` and `.then(console.log)` are basically doing the same thing (although `.then(Promise.resolve...)` makes no sense).

Comment: its just a nature of promise, read more docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to [`Promise#then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) is a function to be called when the Promise is fulfilled. It is called with one argument: the value that the Promise resolved to.

Passing `console.log` as the first argument means that `console.log` will be called and passed the resolved value when the Promise is fulfilled.

It is similar to the following code:

```js
function fn(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback("value"), 500);
}
fn(console.log);
// equivalent to fn(val => console.log(val))
```